# colorbox and jQuery

Tags: jquery, colorbox

SO, I'm not new to Jquery, but I am new to Colorbox and I need help. I was looking for a JQuery that will allow my images to play like a slideshow when the image thumbnail is clicked (like Jquery lightbox but with a slideshow) I was told to try out colorbox. It fits what I need but I'. getting some..strange results.
So far, all the needed files are installed (I downloaded the software from http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox and currently have "example 4" installed or at least trying. All the files and images are in place and installed. 
But when I click on the thumbnail image, the colorbox shows up, but with no image and the borders/corners, ect that come with this particular jquery are all scrambled and I'm viewing a test page in Mozilla. I tried posting the codes..but this thing is giving me a hard time. Hopefully someone knows what I'm talking about.

Thank you for the help, and sorry for the lengthy note..just want this figured out as soon as possible..it's giving me a headache.

Comment: It would probably help to post code samples or a JSFiddle with what you've tried.

Comment: It sounds like you're using Firefox. Have you loaded your test page with Firebug enabled to make sure your resources are all getting loaded properly?

Comment: I just ran into the same problem for the first time ever. I've been using colorbox for almost 2 years now, and never had a problem with it. Now I have the same problem you described, but I'm using it in a jquery plugin I'm writing. I'm also using example 4. I have no idea what the problem is, but I'll make sure to post a solution here if I find what I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you might want to spend some time on its [Beginner's Guide](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/guide) page, and try to have a better understanding of colorbox plugin. Below is the sample code from the guide page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({ opacity:0.5 , rel:'group1' });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class='gallery' href='image1.jpg'>Photo_1</a>
        <a class='gallery' href='image2.jpg'>Photo_2</a>
        <a class='gallery' href='image3.jpg'>Photo_3</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's probably all you need to start off wtih, and then you can modify it as you go, like adding more options to colorbox, changing HTML, etc. You might want to pay more attention to the URLs of your external resources (place css & colorbox-min.js under the root directory in this case)

Also, since you are using Firefox, why don't you install [Firebug Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) for debugging. You can post the errors here if you see any.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out that I had copied some code from an older website, so I was still loading jQuery 1.4.2

Recent versions of colorbox don't work very well with Jquery version less than 1.4.3 (see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/colorbox/yFLOgvP20NI)

After I updated my jQuery library everything looked nice again.